# Lower bound on $F$ under the assumption $\theta F(s)\le sF'(s)$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, functions, asymptotics, integral-inequality

Let $F(s)=\displaystyle \int_0^{s}f(t)\,\mathrm dt$. We suppose that there exists $\theta>2$ such that $\theta F(s)\le f(s)s$ for all $s\in \mathbb{R}$ and that $F(s)>0$ for all $s\in(0,+\infty)$.

How to prove that $F(s)\ge F(1)s^\theta$?

Comment: Did you try to see if $F(s)/s^\theta$ is increasing, by calculating its derivative?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $F(t)>0$ for $t>0$ we have
$$
\frac{F'(t)}{F(t)}\ge \frac{\theta}{t} \quad \forall t>0.
$$
Hence:
$$
\ln\frac{F(s)}{F(1)}=\int_1^s\frac{F'(t)}{F(t)}\,dt \ge \int_1^s\frac{\theta}{t}\,dt=\theta\ln s=\ln s^\theta.
$$
It follows that
$$
F(s)\ge F(1)s^\theta \quad \forall s>0.
$$